# Need to get a numeric value from number field in email

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

I have a custom numeric field: NumberOfOppsWon__c. I tried to put in some conditional logical in my email template based on its value being greater than zero.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(relatedTo.NumberOfOppsWon__c > 0, true, false)}">
...
</apex:outputPanel>
```

When I try to save the email template, I get:

```
Error occurred trying to load the template for preview: The value 'null' is not valid for operator '>'.. Please try editing your markup to correct the problem.
```

Any ideas, tips?

Comment: You may want to consider adding a default value for that field; zero sounds like it would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

I think your NumberOfOppsWon__c field is pointing to null value and you can not compare a null with 0. you can compare like this -

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!relatedTo.NumberOfOppsWon__c != null && 
relatedTo.NumberOfOppsWon__c > 0}">
...
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: The IF-formula isn't really necessary if all it returns is true/false, rendered="{!relatedTo.NumberOfOppsWon__c != null && 
relatedTo.NumberOfOppsWon__c > 0}" should be enough. Readability is of course in the eye of the beholder, but to me that's easier to read as well.

Comment: @Pramod Kumar tried setting default value. Getting same error.

Comment: @dublintech default value of an Integer is null thats why you are getting this error. Initialize it with 0.

Comment: @Pradmod Kumar Yes I did that. The default value is set to 0. And I get the same error.

Comment: It should work. i have tried the same thing at my machine and it is working. Print NumberOfOppsWon__c value and see what it prints

Comment: @Pradmod Kumar the problem happens when I try to save the email template.